# Ajax Popupcontrolextender issues

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a bizarre problem. I have followed the example here (http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/071107-1.aspx) to display an ajax popup, but it is not working properly.

The problem I have is that the image attributes are not set properly, I checked with Firebug and this is what I get on page 1 after load.

```
<img src="StyleSheets/magglass.jpg" id="mainContent_TheGrid_MagGlass_0">
```

Now the bizarre, if I go to page 2, the onmouseover event is set properly for all images and if I come back to page 1, it is set properly too, e.g.

```
<img src="StyleSheets/magglass.jpg" onmouseover="$find('pce0').showPopup(); " id="mainContent_TheGrid_MagGlass_0">
```

I stepped through the code and confirmed that the rowcreated event is firing for my grid, for each row

Any Ideas?

My code is slightly different to the example, see below

```
protected void TheGrid_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        // Programmatically reference the PopupControlExtender
        PopupControlExtender pce = e.Row.FindControl("TheGrid_PopupControlExtender") as PopupControlExtender;

        // Set the BehaviorID
        string behaviorID = string.Concat("pce", e.Row.RowIndex);
        pce.BehaviorID = behaviorID;

        // Programmatically reference the Image control
        Image i = (Image)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("MagGlass");

        // Add the client-side attributes (onmouseover & onmouseout) 
        string OnMouseOverScript = string.Format("$find('{0}').showPopup(); ", behaviorID);


        i.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", OnMouseOverScript);

    }
}
```

The GetDynamicContent Method is below, which adds the hidepopup method.

```
   [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
public static string GetDynamicContent(string contextKey)
{

    GridView MyGrid = (GridView)HttpContext.Current.Session["TheGrid"];

    var MyVar = from GridViewRow MyRow in MyGrid.Rows
                where MyRow.Cells[MyRow.Cells.Count - 1].Text == contextKey
                select MyRow;

    //This is the selected row by the user
    GridViewRow MyGridRow = MyVar.SingleOrDefault();

    //MyGridRow.Cells[3].Text is the log entry.  
    string MyTable = @"<table class=""PopUpTable""><tr><td><textarea class=""textarea"">"
       + MyGridRow.Cells[3].Text + "</textarea></td>";

    //MyGridRow.RowIndex is used to determine the name of popup control for the hidepopup script
    MyTable += "<td><button type=\"button\" class=\"PopUpButton\" onclick=\"$find('pce" + MyGridRow.RowIndex.ToString() + "').hidePopup();\">Close</button></td></tr></table>";

    return MyTable;

}
```

This is the pageIndexChanging event

```
  protected void TheGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{

    TheGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;      

        LoadFromDB();

}
```

The LoadFromDB method here:

```
private void LoadFromDB()
{
    try
    {
        LOGDBDataContext LDC = new LOGDBDataContext(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Constants.ConnectionStringName].ConnectionString);



        string Query = @"DateTimeStamp >= @0 and DateTimeStamp <= @1"; 


        var Tolo = LDC
                   .Logs
                   .Where(Query, this.FromCalendar.SelectedDate, this.ToCalendar.SelectedDate)
                   .OrderBy("DateTimeStamp desc")
                   .Select("new (LogID, DateTimeStamp, Organization, LogEntry, ServerHostname)");


        TheGrid.DataSource = Tolo;
        TheGrid.DataBind();



    }


    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    //do something here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never Mind, found the answer.

1. Poor Debugging
2. A poor attempt at
   clearing the gridview that was not
   invoked by the pagechanging event

Incompetence thy name is yomismo